# Meaning of 'full reality to change'

Tags: meaning, complex-sentences

> Therefore, classic ontology denies any **full reality to change**, **which** is conceived as only accidental and not essential

In the above sentence, which is the object(or complement) of the 'deny'? what is the 'to change' to modify? what is the 'which' substitutes?

Comment: For more context, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_philosophy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object of *deny* is *any full reality*. The word *change* is being used as a noun, and is the object of the preposition *to*, which indicates whose claim is being denied. (Note that this in **not** an instance of the infinitive *to change*.) So this:

> Classical ontology denies any full reality to change.

Basically means:

> Classical ontology denies that change is fully real.

The antecedent of the relative pronoun *which* is the noun *change*. So the second half of the quoted sentence means:

> Change is conceived as only accidental and not essential.